# I have saved my signup details in a csv file and while loging in I want to verify whether the data is valid or not. But I am facing errors

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry, tkinter-button, customtkinter

## Saving Sign Up details

#### **# Function to save the sign-up details to a dictionary and display a confirmation message**

```
def save_sign_up():
        forename = forename_text.get()
        dob = dob_text.get()
        username = username_text.get()
        password = password_text.get()

        # Save the login details to a CSV file
        with open("sign_up.csv", "a") as writer:
            writer.write(f"{forename}, {dob}, {username}, {password}\n")

        sign_up_window.destroy()
```

## **Saving Login details**

#### #Function to save the login details to a CSV file

```
def save_login():
    username = username_text.get()
    password = password_text.get()

    # opening the CSV file
    with open('sign_up.csv', mode='r') as file:

        # reading the CSV file
        cfile = csv.DictReader(file)

        # check if the username and password are valid
        for row in cfile:
            if username == row['username'] and password == row['password']:
                review_label.config(text="Login successful!")
                # Close the login window
                login_window.destroy()
                break
            else:
                review_label.config(text="Invalid username or password. Please try again.")

    # Close the login window
    login_window.destroy()
```

Errors

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "#", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "#", line 52, in save_login
    if username == row['username'] and password == row['password']:
                   ~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
KeyError: 'username'
```

Comment: Remove single quote for username and password.

Comment: Some thoughts/questions: (a) is there a reason you're not using the `csv` module to write the CSV file? (b) your CSV file apparently doesn't include headers, so when your code reads it in, how would it know what the names of the columns are? (c) have you tried `print`ing out each `row` as you read it from `cfile`?

Comment: Answering - a) No there's no specific reason for not using csv module to write. b) Thankyou for noting that now I have added the headers. c) Yes I tried printing out each row but there was not much difference in the output. It would be great if you could help me out to solve this problem. The primary problem here is While I am able to sign in when trying to login i face error as the program is not able to check the sign_up.csv file for the username and password.

Comment: @toyotaSupra there won't be any difference even if I remove the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

There are few issues in your code:

- You need to either adding a header line (used as the keys) at the beginning of the CSV file, or pass the keys when creating `csv.DictReader()`
- there is extra space after the commas in each row of the CSV file
- the `else` block should be the same indentation of the `for` block inside `save_login()`

The updated code:

```py
def save_sign_up():
    forename = forename_text.get()
    dob = dob_text.get()
    username = username_text.get()
    password = password_text.get()

    # Save the login details to a CSV file
    with open("sign_up.csv", "a") as writer:
        # removed extra space after the commas
        writer.write(f"{forename},{dob},{username},{password}\n")

    sign_up_window.destroy()

def save_login():
    username = username_text.get()
    password = password_text.get()

    # opening the CSV file
    with open('sign_up.csv', mode='r') as file:

        # reading the CSV file
        # provide the keys when creating the reader
        cfile = csv.DictReader(file, ('forename', 'dob', 'username', 'password'))

        # check if the username and password are valid
        for row in cfile:
            if username == row['username'] and password == row['password']:
                review_label.config(text="Login successful!")
                # Close the login window
                #login_window.destroy()  # will be called after the for loop
                break
        else:   # same indentation as for
            review_label.config(text="Invalid username or password. Please try again.")

    # Close the login window
    login_window.destroy()   # should it be called actually?
```